# Measure relative position between two IMUs

Tags: imu, teensy, position

I'm trying to create a system where I need to measure the relative orientation of the edge of the arm with respect to its base:

[image]

The apparatus will be like in the diagram above. To measure the relative position I'm currently using two 9DoF IMUs - MPU9250 connected to Teensy LC (one at the edge and the other at the base), and using quaternion values.

The requirement of taking the relative position is, this arm can rotate around the base in all directions (except below the base-surface). and the system itself can rotate in any direction. But while rotating, the arm will not change the position, it'll remain in the initial position.
For example, here is another position the system can be:

[image]

As shown, the relative orientation of the edge has not changed, based on its base. Also I'm not interested in determining the position/direction of the whole system, just interested in the relative position of the edge with respect to the base.

Here are some more examples:
[image]

At the moment I'm using the Madgwick Quaternion update algorithm to calculate the quaternions and use the following equation to calculate the relative orientation:

```
void quatDiff(float* E, float* rw_B)
{
    float B[] = { rw_B[0], -rw_B[1], -rw_B[2], -rw_B[3]};

    float q00 = (E[0] * B[0] - E[1] * B[1] - E[2] * B[2] - E[3] * B[3]);
    float q11 = (E[0] * B[1] + E[1] * B[0] + E[2] * B[3] - E[3] * B[2]);
    float q22 = (E[0] * B[2] - E[1] * B[3] + E[2] * B[0] + E[3] * B[1]);
    float q33 = (E[0] * B[3] + E[1] * B[2] - E[2] * B[1] + E[3] * B[0]);
}
```

E and rw_B are the quaternions return from two IMUs (edge and base).

My questions are:
Is this method a reliable and a valid method to calculate the relative quaternion orientation of two IMUs. 
If so, is this equation is correct for comparing values.

Comment: It's ot really clear to me how these two devices are attached .

Comment: I think it would depend on the drift of your sensors and the algorithms used. https://github.com/mjs513/FreeIMU-Updates

Comment: @MarkoBuršič, I edited the question, hope it's clear now

Comment: In the paper released by Magdwick, there is an explanation of quternion rotation matrix with respect to Earth ground. Now, where did you found the math for yours quatDiff function? Are you sure it will compute the difference?

Comment: Is this relative difference as you are reffering at, only the angle A or B in your picture? Becuse the IMU gives attitude only, angles, not a position.

Comment: I got this quatDiff function from an old lecture note, but it didn't have a reference. Actually, I also have doubts about the function, that's why I want to get it confirmed. 

regards to the "relative position", what i'm referring is edge quaternion values relative to base. I'm not sure it's correct to say, "if the relative position of the edge compared to the base is unchanged - but the whole system is rotating around any axis - the relative quaternion values should not change"

Comment: Here is a more simple example analogous to what I'm trying to do:
if the "base" is the wrist of the hand, and the edge is the fingertip of the index finger, i'm trying to track whether the position of the fingertip changes with respect to the wrist. In this case, Im sitting on a rotating chair, arm is fixed so there's no relative motion between the wrist and the finger, but the chair is rotating. So if i'm correct, the relative quaternions should not change (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Is the use of IMU mandatory? Because if your entire system can not only rotate in place but also move around then you are fighting offset disturbances with end result either reduced precision or increased latency. There are so many alternative sensor options with easy to read outputs, rejection of sideways motion and much better precision, that the choice of IMU looks like the worst possible solution.

Comment: Actually IMU is not the only option. I chosed IMU based on some recommendations by electronic engineers. Can you suggest me some sensors for the described task (my background is in computer science)?

Comment: Rotary encoders, Hall-effect, magnetostrictive, potentiometric, capacitive sensors etc. Pretty much any angular position sensors would be much easier to use than IMU. The choice should be based on desired precision and mechanical design. Here is a [nice guide](https://www.zettlex.com/articles/position-sensors-dummys-guide/) from one of the best sensor manufacturers in the world. IMHO the Hall effect sensors provide best combination of price, longevity and precision for this application

Comment: For example, if your pivot has U-joint design (as in drive shafts) then you can use two angular sensors on axles. If it is ball head kind (as in camera tripods) then you can use two linear position sensors between the base and an arm and compensate for nonlinearity of motion with simple trigonometric function in software